# Conditional data import to mysql from CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to be able to have a CSV file with 6 Columns,  I’m trying to figure out the best way to do it..

Here is what I have now and it works for 2 columns,

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h2>Updated:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
    $shipdate = date('Y-m-d');

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="UPDATE table
        SET abc='$data[1]', def='".$shipdate."'
        WHERE g=$data[0]";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

        print "</br>Updated Successfully</br>";

        //view upload form
        }else { ?>

        Import Numbers<br />

        <form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>
        <input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>


    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I want to now have columns 3-6 update only if there is a value in them,  I have tried:

But it didn’t work, I’m assuming because I can’t reference $data[x] outside of the while clause?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Would `REPLACE INTO` work here?

Comment: I advise you to move away from mysql to either PDO statements or mysqli as it's now depreciated. What are the column names in your table and what are the corresponding rows in the file?

Comment: @Skewled the columns corresponding rows are... PO#, INVOICE, shippign cost, FEDEX TRACKING, UPS TRACKING, ONTRAC TRACKIGN SHIPPING COST, todays date: orders_id, vendor_invoice_number, fedex_track_num, ups_tracking_num, ontrac_track_num, ship_cost, ship_date